# Django - How to add extra fields to User model?

Tags: python, django

I need to **add new fields to the " real Django User model "**.
Why? Because **I have two forms** in my template with post methods **in two different pages**.

And I created **two models**, **each one saves the corresponding form data in the database.**

In my views I had to write **two different functions** for the forms pages.

The 1st one: when there is a post request, it saves the data in the **1st Model**.

The 2nd one: Does the same as 1st but it saves the data in the **2nd Model**.

I tried to **create another new model3 which contains model1 + model2 fields** (*Didn't delete the previous models*)! But when I submit the 1st form it saves data in an object, and when I submit the 2nd form data in another new object of model3 !

So I canceled this method and now I have to try another way to do the task, So I saved the 1st form data ( which are a login info ( email, pass ) and when a user submits the form, it creates a new user with

```
user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST.get("email"),request.POST.get("email"),password)
```

**That worked fine**, and now I can modify the credentials in the views with just user.username = newemail and user.password with newpassword.. but I couldn't do that with the 2nd form because the User model hasn't as much fields as the Model2! And also when I try it with

```
data = Model3(fielname = request.POST.get("addressLineForExample")
data.save()
```

it causes an error saying that I didn't specify for which user id I am going to save it!

I've seen videos and docs about the **OneToOneField** method! Then I figured out it **just shows the model3 fields in the user page** in 127.0.0.1:8000/admin, and not adding real fields to the User Model!

I came with the idea of changing user.newaddedfield = any Model3 field! I just want to realize it that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I went back with **creating another new model3 which contains model1 + model2 fields**

Then, when I submit the first form, I do:

```
data = Model3(field1 = request.POST.get("ValueOfThe1stFormField1")
data.save()
```

Now the Model3 modem will be filled with the 1st form's data but not yet with the 2nd's.

So in the 2nd function where a user should submit data in the 2nd form, I do an update to the related model3 object like:

```
Model3.objects.filter(field1=field1OfThe1stForm).update(field2=anything, field3=anything,...)
```

Hope it helps anyone who is trying to merge two (or more) models in one other model  that should contain all of the previous model fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend Django's `AbstractUser` to create your own custom user model on top of Django's `User` model. For example:

File: `project/user/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    custom_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then you need to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

in your terminal for creating related model in the database.

In order to see this model in your admin page, register the model using the following snippet:

File: `project/user/admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

- P.S. I strongly recommend adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"` to `project/project/settings.py` in order to be able to fully use Django's default User functionalities (including Django Rest Framework's authentication ingtegrations).
- P.S. Make sure you have the app's name listed under `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but,
Should I change something in

 `user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)` or not?

And Will this affect on the typical User's attributes and methods and..?

Thanks again.